# Executing a FOR loop outside a function in PgAdmin fails with "syntax error at or near "for""

Tags: postgresql

Why am I unable to just execute the following in PgAdmin with F5 (Run):

```
for temprow in 
   select * from recalls_t where user_id in (select id from users_t where user_name like '%PRF15D%')
loop
   for r in 1..50
   loop
       insert into events_t (id, gui_event_id)
                   values (nextval('seq'), temprow.id);
    end loop;
end loop;
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "for"
LINE 2: for temprow in 
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 7
```

My goal is  to insert dummy rows in a FOR loop. I don't need a function or anything else.

Comment: Because the `plpgsql` language just is one of many `pl` languages supported by extensions of PostgreSQL (plpgsql, plpythonu, plperl, even plsh) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xplang.html Only one default language supported by PostgreSQL is SQL (yes, for `do` blocks the default language is PL/pgSQL but IMO it is more exception then rule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/pgSQL code can only be run in the context of a PL/pgSQL function or `do` block.

But you don't need a loop to begin with:

```
insert into events_t (id, gui_event_id)
select nextval('seq'), id,
from recalls_t 
where user_id in (select id 
                  from users_t 
                  where user_name like '%PRF15D%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `plpgsql` is not executable SQL. You want to use the `DO` statement. For documentation, have a look here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html

You can use this like a "one time function".